# Generating random string and checking if is equal to a static string[Python]

Tags: python, string, random

```
characters ='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz '

def monkey():
    return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(5))

def checkif():
     checkstring = "seven"
     randString = monkey()
     count = 1

     while(randString != checkstring):
           if(randString) == (checkstring):
              print(count)
              return True
           else:
              randString = monkey()
              count = count + 1
```

I want to generate a random string and check whether or not the string is equal to a static string, then and I want the program to keep running until the randomly generating string is equal to the static string("seven" in this case). Random string generation works fine but my loop seems to run infinitely, rather than stopping after the condition has been reached. Could anyone help me properly stop the infinite loop?

Comment: There are 27^5 = 14348907 (~ 14 million) such strings. How long is "indefinitely" in your book? I suspect it's smaller than the expected time for "seven" to be produced. Now, if the loop was still running after, say, 28 million iterations, then you can start worrying.

Comment: Does the OP realise the absurdity?

Comment: Note that the `if (randstring) == (checkstring)` will never be True, because the `while` right above it just checked for the opposite. But that's not the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are

```
27**5
Out[77]: 14348907
```

Possible permutations of `monkey`.  I'd imagine you're just not waiting long enough.

However, you *do* have a bug that will result in `count` never getting printed:

```
while(randString != checkstring):
           if(randString) == (checkstring):
              print(count)
              return True
           else:
              randString = monkey()
              count = count + 1
```

Your `while` condition will break out of the loop before that `if` block gets checked.  Change it to `while True:` and let your break condition break out.

Also, optimization:

```
def monkey():
    return ''.join([random.choice(characters) for i in range(5)])
```

`''.join`ing a list comprehension works faster than `join`ing a generator expression.

So, revisiting all the code (with some minor syntactical upgrades thrown in, and a timer):

```
def monkey():
    return ''.join([random.choice(characters) for i in range(5)])

def checkif():
     checkstring = "seven"
     randString = monkey()
     count = 1
     start = time.time()

     while True:
           if randString == checkstring:
              print('found it in {} seconds; took {} iterations'.format(time.time() - start, count))
              return
           else:
              randString = monkey()
              count = count + 1
```

Outputs:

```
found it in 62.897234201431274 seconds; took 12298282 iterations
```

Obviously your mileage may vary on finding the monkey :-)

Comment: Better yet, move the current then block to after the loop and only have the current `else` block inside it. Less error/bug prone and more clear, in my opinion. Also, can you cite a source on the list comprehension being faster? That surprised me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `monkey()` method can create 27^5 == 14348907 (14 million) different strings. It will (statistically) take quite some time until the specific string `seven` is randomly created. Wait longer.

Answer (score 0):

`27*27*27*27*27 = 14348907` possibilities. It will take a long time to get a string equals to the desired.

You can try with a *smaller-length* test:

```
def checkif():
     checkstring = "se" # length:2
     randString = monkey()
     count = 1

     while True: # Infinite loop
           if(randString) == (checkstring): # This will take care of loop exit
              print(count)
              return True
           else:
              randString = monkey()
              count = count + 1
```

and change `monkey()` length result (just for testing). With this smaller example, you can see that the program works as intended:

```
def monkey():
    return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(2)) # length: 2
```